# android: layout not rendering correctly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a bunch of linear layouts inside relative layout, and I am having issues with it rendering

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="110dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_above="@id/ivIcon"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEstTime"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="8sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The output of the code is

[image]

The output I want is

[image]

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Result after using @Shahar's code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/ivIcon"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvEstTime"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvEst"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="8sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Your code almost did the trick, but the status 'tvStatus' is not touching the bottom of its parent. see the edit part of the question

Comment: I have solved it by giving an id to `LinearLayout` and setting layout parameters of `tvStatus` text view to `android:layout_alignTop="@id/linear"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear"`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to make your `LinearLayout` that has `tvEstTime` and `tvEst` orientation to `vertical`, so it can come under each other. Also get rid of the `android:layout_weight="1"` in `tvEst`. Another thing you can try is see if it is showing without the textApperance settings. Otherwise I tried adding static text and it showed it to me.